# fermentation in soil bacteria

Tags: cellular-respiration, fermentation, soil, anaerobic-respiration

I am doing a project on microbial fuel cell. For the purpose of the efficiency of the question, MFCs can be summarized to:

> Devices that use anaerobic bacteria as the catalysts to oxidize organic and inorganic matter and generate current. [I referenced this article](http://web.mit.edu/pweigele/www/SoBEI/Info_files/Logan%202006%20Environ%20Sci%20Technol.pdf)

While writing the analysis I was quite confused about the fermentation process in which anaerobic bacteria in soil undergo. Usually the fermentation process and its byproduct would be specified, however, in this case there are numerous bacteria that the soil contains.

I want to ask if there is a specified fermentation process that the soil bacteria undergo (which is probably not the case), or is it unknown so I should just talk about fermentation in general.

Thanks in advance!

ps. it would be greatly appreciated if a link to some websites or articles that would possibly help me is included :)